# SSRS formatting several records in on line

Tags: reporting-services, format

I have an employee database table that has the times that every employee went into work or went for break.  The table has a record for every time a employee signed in or out like this:

Name    |     Type         |     Date

---

john sil  |   ClockIN     |  10/11/2020 9:00 AM
john sil    | BreakIN      |  10/11/2020 12:00 PM
john sil   |  BreakOut   | 10/11/2020 12:30 PM
john sil    | ClockOut   |  10/11/2020 5:00 PM

I would like to group those records in one to appear all in one line instead of four.  Something like this:

Name       |   Date     |   ClockIn   |  BreakIn  |    BreakOut   |  ClockOut

---

John sil   |  10/11/2020   |  9:00 AM  |  12:00 PM  |  12:30PM   |   5:00 PM

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Matrix in SSRS was made for this kind of data.

Add a Matrix to your report.

In the Grouping Window, go to Group Properties. Add a Grouping to the Row and Group On Date without the time. Sort by the date expression.

```
=Format(Fields!Date.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")"
```

This will combine all the records for a single day.

Use the Date field for the Cell value and use 'mm/DD/yyyy' as the Format Property of the Date text box.

Right Click on the RowGroup and Add Group -> Parent Group.

Group on Employee and Sort by Employee. Use the Name for the Text Box value. This will break up the days by employee.

Click on the Column Group in the Group Window and go to Group Properties. Group On Type.

Go to the Sort tab. Add a Sort By

`=IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "ClockIN", 1, 2)`

This will make the Clock In come up first.

And then add a second level by Fields!Type.Value. The sorting by name will work for the other Types. The Column grouping will break up the daily data by the different punches.